# Where is OBD port location

Tags: honda, civic, obd-ii

Where is the OBD II port on a Honda Civic 2012 located? A picture would be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look just to the left of the steering wheel underneath the dash, in the driver's footwell, you should see the white connector.

[image]